# Could you use Html 5 canvas to calculate the distance you travelled along a river?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

My thought was that you could draw a line that traversed the river and then if you knew the total distance of the river you divide the line's pixel length by the distance.

So if your line was 760px and the distance of the river was 20 miles then 760 / 20 = 38px = 1 mile.

Of course if my line was just a straight line or a series of lines this would be fairly simple. However, I would like my line to reflect the contours of the river and as such would be curved in places.

Firstly, is this a good method for plotting distance travelled along a river? If not what would work better (i have a feeling my maths is wrong!).

If this is a good method how would i take into account the curved nature of the line and how this might affect the pixel length of the line?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to measure the contours of the river as to my understanding it would be calculated as if it was a straight line.

Comment: Why do you need to draw to a canvas to measure the length of a line?  It doesn't sound like you need HTML5 canvas for this.

Comment: @AshleysBrain I need to deliver this in the browser so other users can see the distance they have travelled down a river. I don't know how you would do it just in the DOM and I don't know Flash so Canvas seemed the best option for me.

Comment: Note that you [can do this already in Google Earth](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22365&topic=23730&answer=148134): create a path (as an arbitrary number of straight path segments) and get the total length of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the length of a river is similar to calculating the [Length of an Arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_an_arc)
.

Even if you draw the river exactly as you want it in an canvas(or in any Raster Image for that matter), and then count the amount of blue pixels, you would only be able to get an approximate answer as close as  canvaswidth / riverdistance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use miles (because its too crude). Use something shorter instead (I'd use meters, but ymmv).
Then just draw a line along the curvature of the river and count the pixels of that line, every pixel represents a given distance. (e.G. one pixel could represent 150 meters)

Comment: How would you count the number of pixels along the line? Is there a method in canvas that would return how long in pixels a line was? Also if you put a curve on the line wouldn't that curve be made up of a number of pixels some of which would be 0.6 of a pixel for example?